# Can we use static files like txt as datasource to create my SSRS reports?

Tags: file, text, reporting-services, static

Can we use static files like txt as datasource to create my SSRS reports?

Comment: What about setting up an ODBC connection to the text file and pointing the Data Source to the ODBC connection? I haven't tested (hence just a comment at this stage) but no reason this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

No, the only data source in the form of files compatible with SSRS are XML files. You can read about data sources here here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-uk/library/ms159219.aspx

and here is the article about using XML files as data sources:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129(v=sql.90).aspx

If that is not satisfactory you have to set up a database and load the data there.

EDIT:

I found a link in which there is alternative solution to using flat files as data sources (however, it requires some programming to be done):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2f72a9cb-9512-4ac7-8392-2d5d21186385/text-file-data-source?forum=sqlreportingservices